# Stationary sets in $\kappa$ of countable cofinality

Tags: set-theory

This is exercise 47 of chapter 7 of "Introduction to Modern Set Theory" by Judith Roitman.
The problem is:

> Show that if $\kappa$ has countable cofinality then $S \subseteq \kappa$ is a stationary subset of $\kappa$ iff $\kappa \setminus S$ is bounded below $\kappa$.

I am trying to prove the forward direction (starting with a stationary set and showing there is a bound on $\kappa \setminus S$).

$S \subseteq \kappa$ is said to be **stationary** iff $S \cap C \neq \emptyset$ for all $C$ club in $\kappa$. A **club** set is one that is closed and unbounded in $\kappa$. This text defines closed as: $C \subseteq \kappa$ is **closed** in $\kappa$ iff for all $A \subseteq C$ if A is not cofinal in $\kappa$ then $\sup(A) \in C$.

If $\operatorname{cf}(\kappa) \lt \omega$ then $\kappa$ has a greatest element $\alpha$, and $\{ \alpha \}$ is club in $\kappa$ so $\alpha \in S$ and $\kappa \setminus S$ is bounded below $\kappa$.

But I run into trouble if $\operatorname{cf}(\kappa) = \omega$. Here is what I can figure out:

Suppose for the sake of a contradiction that $\kappa \setminus S$ is unbounded. Then $\kappa \setminus S$ would be club if for every $A \subseteq \kappa \setminus S$ not cofinal in $\kappa$, $\sup(A) \in \kappa \setminus S$. But $\kappa \setminus S$ cannot be club since then $S$ would intersect it. Thus there exists $A \subseteq \kappa \setminus S$ not cofinal in $\kappa$ such that $\sup(A) \notin \kappa \setminus S$, hence $\sup(A) \in S$. If $|A| \lt \omega$, then $A$ has a greatest element $\alpha$, and $\sup(A)=\alpha \in A \subseteq \kappa \setminus S$. Thus $|A| \geq \omega$. The problem is solved if $\kappa = \omega$ since every set not cofinal in $\omega$ is finite, meaning $\kappa \setminus S$ would be club and we would have a contradiction. But for $\kappa \gt \omega$ I'm stumped.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Suppose that $\kappa\setminus S$ is unbounded. Since $\operatorname{cf}\kappa=\omega$, there is a strictly increasing sequence $\langle\alpha_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ in $\kappa$ that is cofinal in $\kappa$. Use this to construct a strictly increasing sequence $\langle\beta_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ in $\kappa\setminus S$ that is cofinal in $\kappa$; then $\{\beta_n:n\in\omega\}$ will be a club set disjoint from $S$.